# nginx reverse proxy redirect to CloudFlare with Headers

Tags: nginx, redirect, header, cloudflare

I am struggling with configuring Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect based on headers, the proxy server is pointing to Cloudflare, and the backend servers `proxy_pass` require a Basic Authentication which passing by adding `proxy_set_proxy` or `add_header`.

The issue I having is the `Authorization: Basic xXyXyZCc` not being passed to Cloudflare.

#### config

Mapping config

```
    # CUSTOM MAPPING STARTS HERE #
    # map HTTP header Business-Code to a variable
        map $http_business_name $service_upstream {
                XYZ         KPR;
                ABC           GKO;
                default         default;
        }

        # map HTTP header Service-Name-Code to a HTTP header named host_dynamic
        map $http_business_name $host_dynamic {
                XYZ         admin.xyz.com;
                ABC           admin.abc.ac;
                default                 default;
        }
        # map HTTP header BUSINESS-NAME to HTTP header Authorization
                map $http_business_name $basic_auth {
                XYZ         "Basic 123XYZabc";
        }
```

server config

```
    server {
                listen 443;
                server_name admin.abc.com;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$host_dynamic$uri redirect;
        }

                 upstream KPR {
                    server 127.0.0.1:443;
              }

                server {
                listen 80 default;
                location / {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic 123XYZabc";
                        add_header Authorization "Basic 123XYZabc";
                        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
                        add_header Auhtorization $basic_auth;
                        proxy_pass http://$service_upstream;

                }

        }
```

#### curl --verbose

as you can see the Authorization header is not being passed to Cloudflare although it's defined as `add_header` or `set_proxy_header`.

```
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) port 80 (#0)
> GET /admin-apis/business/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 1.2.3.4
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> BUSINESS-NAME: ABC
> Authorization: Basic 123XYZabc
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.17.8
< Date: Mon, 08 Mar 2021 17:12:26 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 145
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://admin.abc.com/admin-apis/business/1
< Authorization: Basic 123XYZabc
< Auhtorization: Basic 123XYZabc
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host q.2.3.4 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://admin.abc.com/admin-apis/business/1'
*   Trying 5.6.7.8...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to admin.abc.com (xx.yy.zz.aa) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
*  start date: Oct  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Oct  4 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "admin.abc.com" matched cert's "*.abc.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x135fbf0)
> GET /admin-apis/business/1 HTTP/2
> Host: admin.abc.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> BUSINESS-NAME: ABC
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
< HTTP/2 403
< date: Mon, 08 Mar 2021 17:12:27 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 63
< set-cookie: __cfduid=d3e66c88100fa1d794c3e034bbbcaceca1615223546; expires=Wed, 07-Apr-21 17:12:26 GMT; path=/; domain=.abc.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
< x-frame-options: DENY
< vary: Accept-Language, Origin
< content-language: en
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< referrer-policy: same-origin
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< cf-request-id: 08b46c7a5700002a1b1001f000000001
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< report-to: {"max_age":604800,"group":"cf-nel","endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=7IF25wHOwjD1VSJnNy1IHwdZH2bm2BjnNAwDbsB4NIN9DzUYVV2EnNkRFZZTupBhG6XYmHgKysBzYNevQL4rBgq9HFyhkesQ4rLi8Y2b89gKk1Vo"}]}
< nel: {"max_age":604800,"report_to":"cf-nel"}
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 62cdb03d5a3b2a1b-IAD
<
```